# How can I get BCrypt to interpret my key as hex?

Tags: visual-c++, cryptography, bcrypt, hmac, sha512

I'm trying to interact with an API which takes GET and POST requests which include a signature derived from a message and my private key, hashed using HMAC SHA512. The docs give an example:

key (in base-64):

```
bEDtDJnW0y/Ll4YZitxb+D5sTNnEpQKH67EJRCmQCqN9cvGiB8+IHzB7HjsOs3mSlxLmu4aiPDRpe9anuWzylw==
```

message:

```
/account/balance1515058794242
```

should produce the following (base-64) signature:

```
NjqZ8Mgdkj6hrtY/xdKBy1S0kLjU2tA7G+pR2TdOBF45b7+evfpzGH/C/PiNHEDvuiRChRBlRo3AGJ7Gcvlwqw==
```

The docs also state that the key needs to be decoded from base-64 before using in the hmac, but is unclear about what format it should be in.

I've been playing around with online hmac generators and can replicate the example signature with no issue. For example, at https://www.liavaag.org/English/SHA-Generator/HMAC/  - input the above key as input type = Base-64, the above message string as input type = TEXT, and output type = base-64, and the output signature is the same as above. It also works fine when I give the key as HEX-type  and use the hex equivalent:

```
6C40ED0C99D6D32FCB9786198ADC5BF83E6C4CD9C4A50287EBB1094429900AA37D72F1A207CF881F307B1E3B0EB379929712E6BB86A23C34697BD6A7B96CF297
```

BUT I cannot replicate the example signature using my own program using BCrypt. It seems that the BCrypt hmac is interpreting my key as 'TEXT'-type input in the same way as the online generator. That is, when I give the key as the hex string:

```
CONST BYTE key[] = { "6C40ED0C99D6D32FCB9786198ADC5BF83E6C4CD9C4A50287EBB1094429900AA37D72F1A207CF881F307B1E3B0EB379929712E6BB86A23C34697BD6A7B96CF297" };
```

I get an output signature (in hex) of:

```
16ab16ed3874fab51dbda66155edf269883d128de6067d77762dcee4129f1612b36fc556df10beb358c81262d034efe4c50d68d89ac43606df4318a8af56b
```

On the online generator I get the same output when I use that hex string (6C40...) as TEXT type key and ouput as HEX.

Is there any way I can force BCrypt to interpret my key as hex? I've even tried declaring the key as hex literals, i.e:

```
CONST BYTE key[] = { 0x6C, 0x40, 0xed, 0x0c, 0x99, 0xd6, 0xd3, 0x2f, 
                         0xCB, 0x97, 0x86, 0x19, 0x8a, 0xdc, 0x5b, 0xf8,
                         0x3E, 0x6c, 0x4c, 0xd9, 0xc4, 0xa5, 0x02, 0x87,
                         0xeb, 0xb1, 0x09, 0x44, 0x29, 0x90, 0x0a, 0xa3,
                         0x7d, 0x72, 0xf1, 0xa2, 0x07, 0xcf, 0x88, 0x1f,
                         0x30, 0x7b, 0x1e, 0x3b, 0x0e, 0xb3, 0x79, 0x92,
                         0x97, 0x12, 0xe6, 0xbb, 0x86, 0xa2, 0x3c, 0x34,
                         0x69, 0x7b, 0xd6, 0xa7, 0xb9, 0x6c, 0xf2, 0x97 };
```

But this gives another, different signature. At least the hex string key is getting something sort of like replicating the online converter. Sorry for any confusion around why I'm using hex instead of base-64, which is what I'll eventually need to use - it's just an extra complicating step at the moment, so for now I'm just trying to get the hex equivalent working, and then I can concentrate on encoding it as base-64. The hex equivalent of the base-64 signature I'm trying to get is:

```
363a99f0c81d923ea1aed63fc5d281cb54b490b8d4dad03b1bea51d9374e045e396fbf9ebdfa73187fc2fcf88d1c40efba2442851065468dc0189ec672f970ab
```

Full code I'm using is below:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <bcrypt.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "bcrypt.lib") 
#define NT_SUCCESS(Status)          (((NTSTATUS)(Status)) >= 0)

#define STATUS_UNSUCCESSFUL         ((NTSTATUS)0xC0000001L)

#include <fstream>

int hexToInt(char ch)
{
    return 0;
}


void __cdecl wmain(
    int                      argc,
    __in_ecount(argc) LPWSTR *wargv)
{
    std::wofstream fout;
    fout.open("signature.txt");


    BCRYPT_ALG_HANDLE       hAlg = NULL;
    BCRYPT_HASH_HANDLE      hHash = NULL;
    NTSTATUS                status = STATUS_UNSUCCESSFUL;
    DWORD                   cbData = 0,
        cbHash = 0,
        cbHashObject = 0;
    PBYTE                   pbHashObject = NULL;
    PBYTE                   pbHash = NULL;


    CONST BYTE message[] = { "/account/balance1515058794242" };
    CONST BYTE key[] = { "6C40ED0C99D6D32FCB9786198ADC5BF83E6C4CD9C4A50287EBB1094429900AA37D72F1A207CF881F307B1E3B0EB379929712E6BB86A23C34697BD6A7B96CF297" };




    //open an algorithm handle
    if (!NT_SUCCESS(status = BCryptOpenAlgorithmProvider(
        &hAlg,
        BCRYPT_SHA512_ALGORITHM,
        NULL,
        BCRYPT_ALG_HANDLE_HMAC_FLAG)))
    {
        fout << "**** Error 0x%x returned by BCryptOpenAlgorithmProvider\n" << status;
        goto Cleanup;
    }

    //calculate the size of the buffer to hold the hash object
    if (!NT_SUCCESS(status = BCryptGetProperty(
        hAlg,
        BCRYPT_OBJECT_LENGTH,
        (PBYTE)&cbHashObject,
        sizeof(DWORD),
        &cbData,
        0)))
    {
        fout << "**** Error 0x%x returned by BCryptGetProperty\n" << status;
        goto Cleanup;
    }

    //allocate the hash object on the heap
    pbHashObject = (PBYTE)HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(), 0, cbHashObject);
    if (NULL == pbHashObject)
    {
        fout << "**** memory allocation failed\n";
        goto Cleanup;
    }

    //calculate the length of the hash
    if (!NT_SUCCESS(status = BCryptGetProperty(
        hAlg,
        BCRYPT_HASH_LENGTH,
        (PBYTE)&cbHash,
        sizeof(DWORD),
        &cbData,
        0)))
    {
        fout << "**** Error 0x%x returned by BCryptGetProperty\n" << status;
        goto Cleanup;
    }

    //allocate the hash buffer on the heap
    pbHash = (PBYTE)HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(), 0, cbHash);
    if (NULL == pbHash)
    {
        fout << "**** memory allocation failed\n";
        goto Cleanup;
    }

    //create a hash
    if (!NT_SUCCESS(status = BCryptCreateHash(
        hAlg,
        &hHash,
        pbHashObject,
        cbHashObject,
        (PBYTE)key,
        sizeof(key) - 1,
        0)))
    {
        fout << "**** Error 0x%x returned by BCryptCreateHash\n" << status;
        goto Cleanup;
    }

    //hash some data
    if (!NT_SUCCESS(status = BCryptHashData(
        hHash,
        (PBYTE)message,
        sizeof(message) - 1,
        0)))
    {
        fout << "**** Error 0x%x returned by BCryptHashData\n" << status;
        goto Cleanup;
    }

    //close the hash
    if (!NT_SUCCESS(status = BCryptFinishHash(
        hHash,
        pbHash,
        cbHash,
        0)))
    {
        fout << "**** Error 0x%x returned by BCryptFinishHash\n" << status;
        goto Cleanup;
    }


    fout << "\nThe hash is:  \n";
    for (DWORD i = 0; i < cbHash; i++)
    {
        fout <<  std::hex << pbHash[i];
    }



Cleanup:

    if (hAlg)
    {
        BCryptCloseAlgorithmProvider(hAlg, 0);
    }

    if (hHash)
    {
        BCryptDestroyHash(hHash);
    }

    if (pbHashObject)
    {
        HeapFree(GetProcessHeap(), 0, pbHashObject);
    }

    if (pbHash)
    {
        HeapFree(GetProcessHeap(), 0, pbHash);
    }


    fout.close();
};
```

Comment: Hexadecimals is a *representation in text* of a byte array. So `CONST BYTE key[] = { 0x6C, ... };` is the right way of creating a byte array. However, if only a single bit of the input key or data differs you'll get a different binary value as hash. So you should e.g. also make sure that the input is encoded correctly using the right *character encoding*, e.g. UTF-8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the `CONST BYTE key[] = { 0x6C, ... };` method of specifying your key. Keys and input data are *binary data*, represented as *byte arrays* in most programming languages. Hexadecimals and base 64 are two ways of *representing* or *encoding* binary values so that they can be used as printable text.

However, if you use a byte array then `sizeof` will return the number of actual bytes. Arrays aren't null terminated, so there is no reason to remove the final null byte. So `sizeof(key) - 1` will remove the last byte of the key as input parameter, rather than remove the non-existent null byte.

The message string *is* null terminated, so it should work well. You may however explicitly want to mention that the message needs to be US-ASCII or explicitly encode the string (e.g. to UTF-8).

Comment: By the way, the signature created by the other application is definitely correct.

Comment: Thanks so much Maarten! Changing "sizeof(key) - 1" to "sizeof(key)" worked perfectly!